# Merge query with two different WHERE clauses/conditions in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: `users`, `accounts` and `scores`. Each query is actually giving me the desired results:

```
-- This will return all user ids with a count of "calculated" scores
SELECT u.id AS user_id, count(1) AS total FROM scores s
  INNER JOIN accounts a ON s.account_id = a.id
  INNER JOIN user u ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.status = 'CALCULATED'
GROUP BY user_id;

-- This will return all user ids with a count of non-calculated scores
SELECT u.id AS user_id, count(1) AS failures FROM scores s
  INNER JOIN accounts a ON s.account_id = a.id
  INNER JOIN user u ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.status <> 'CALCULATED'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

But I would like to return something like this: `user id`, `total`, `failures`...all in one query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with conditional aggregation. Conditions in `SUM` return 1 or 0 depending on the condition being satisfied.

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id,
SUM(s.status='CALCULATED'),
SUM(s.status<>'CALCULATED') AS total 
FROM scores s
INNER JOIN accounts a ON s.account_id = a.id
INNER JOIN user u ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: ...that was quick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you can simplify your query, because the `user` table is (presumably) not needed:

```
SELECT a.user_id,
       SUM(s.status = 'CALCULATED') as num_calc,
       SUM(s.status <> 'CALCULATED') AS num_notcalc 
FROM scores s INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     ON s.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.user_id;
```

Your queries are giving the right answer, but you might also need to be careful about `NULL` values.  If that's a concern, use `<=>` the `NULL`-safe equality operator:

```
SELECT a.user_id,
       SUM(s.status = 'CALCULATED') as num_calc,
       SUM(NOT s.status <=> 'CALCULATED') AS num_notcalc 
FROM scores s INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     ON s.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.user_id;
```

Comment: Indeed, the `users` table is not needed with this approach; also the use of the `NULL`-safe equality operator is a super-nice tip. Thanks!